# First steps: Analyze directory hierarchy of XMLs

Tags: xml, basex

I am just getting started on using BaseX. For that I downloaded basex97.zip and extracted it.
My xml data files reside in a directory I will call DATA, and in there are multiple directories with the XMLs sitting on different levels.

I started BaseX by doubleclicking the BaseX.jar, and the GUI came up.
In the left of the Editor window I configured my DATA directory. A tree view allows me to see the correct directory structure. Then I configured the filename filter to be `*.xml`, and an additional list view shows me that BaseX found the files I want.

Next I tried to write some queries, and trivial ones work: If I put `<test/>` into the editor and execture, the Result window will show the expected output.

But how do I take it from here? Actually I want to run a queries like `//text` and would assume BaseX to go through all the XML files and return all elements named `text` - regardless in which file or at which position in the file it is found.

Comment: From the description it's not 100% clear if you created a new BaseX database and imported the files from your DATA directory in it. If you did, then queries like `//text` should indeed find `text` elements from all documents in the database. If they do not, I would look for a XML namespace issue.

Comment: I did not create a database and did not import the documents. Namespaces are not used in my documents.

Comment: Then creating a database and importing your files is what you need to do.

Comment: In so many tutorials I see the database creation, but I do not see how data is imported. My solution right now works without.

Comment: When creating a database there is the "Input file or directory" and the "File patterns (separated by commas)" input field. These are used to specify the initial data to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure out the correct query. The main part was that I had to use a collection configured with the full path to my documents like so:

```
let $collection := collection("/full/path/to/DATA")
for $t in $collection//text
return $t
```

This seems to return the expected data. I will now focus on creating better FLOWR statements.